# Trying to get data from Mysql db (Spring Boot + Vaadin)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm trying to get and write data to Mysql Db using Spring Boot & Vaadin. I'm new in Spring and it's too boringly to make simple web project with all of Spring's configurations. So I decided to use Spring Boot. And now my headache is - getting and writing data to Mysql Db. I wrote in application.properties configuration for DB, also "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create" create new table in db (if it's not exists), but no data loaded and no data added to db table. As I see from this doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html there is no need to write from beginning some classes to connecting db and getting data... 
Please help. https://github.com/AntonKostyukewicz/VaadinCrud - here is my sources of project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Vaadin JPA Container add-on? If you are willing to talk to the DB in JPA, that's an excellent option. https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/jpacontainer/jpacontainer-overview.html